# How can I get to show a picture from file on my jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, image

I have my picture in the directory Images, next to the notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to be in a Markdown cell:

```markdown
![](Images/Image_name.png)
```

Comment: you missed the code

Comment: Sorry, here you go: ![](Images/Image_name.png)